# regex extract a text between string

Tags: regex, vb.net

are not so expert with regex
i have this string:

> Your value is 1, Your password is 39 - OK.

i would capture 3 results.

1

39

OK

i'm search on web but not find solutions
thanks

Comment: First two can be get by using `(\d+)` and last by `OK` or `(\S+)$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^Your value is ([0-9]*), Your password is ([0-9]*) - ([^ ]*)\.$
```

here => http://regexr.com/3ctu4